# Warning popping up in terminal window when Gedit is opened

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, gedit

> (gedit:15131): WARNING: Could not load theme icon text-x-generic: Icon 'text-x-generic' not present in theme Adwaita

This aforementioned warning sign pops up when I open the "gedit" text editor via the Terminal. Would you please be able to help me to fix this problem.....

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: There is no problem, that is only a warning.  Gedit should still work fine.  If you don't want to see that warning,  try launching it with a `gedit 2>/dev/null` or pressing Alt+F2 then running it from the application finder window.

Comment: But it says: "text-x-generic" not present in theme

Comment: That's a warning, not an error.

Comment: It is a warning and if you wish to try to resolve it try reinstalling / installing gnome icon theme.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-icon-theme

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with running the geany editor. I had to install the full package:

```
sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full
```

Comment: This actually worked. It fixed not only the `adwaita` icon theme issue but also the `breeze` icon theme issue.

Comment: This also fixed `meld` for me - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That is a warning and not an error so it should not cause any problems.

If you want to try to resolve it, install or reinstall gnome icon theme

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-icon-theme

If that does not work, try to find what package provides the icon:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

To search in which package a file is included, enter:

```
apt-file search text-x-generic
```

If that fails try

```
for i in /usr/share/icons/*; do sudo gtk-update-icon-cache $i; done
```

If that fails, file a bug report.

Comment: gtk-update-icon-cache: No theme index file.

Answer (score 0):

Date 2020 March 14, and I was getting similar WARNING messages in Terminal from Gedit and EOG, of missing 'image-loading' in theme Adwaita. Installing adwaita-icon-theme-full per instructions given by user3860088 in *2018 September* fixed the annoyance. Many thanks for this information.

$  lsb_release -d ; uname -rp ; gnome-shell --version ; echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
Description: Ubuntu 19.10
5.3.0-40-generic x86_64
GNOME Shell 3.34.1
wayland