# WSLg Ubuntu app icons not showing up on taskbar

Tags: icons, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently upgraded to Windows 11 and decided to try out WSLg and some Linux GUI apps. To that end, I got Eye of GNOME for viewing images.

However, when I open the app, the icon in the taskbar is the default WSLg icon of the penguin, and I don't know why. I even installed the [Adwaita Icon Package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940722/warning-popping-up-in-terminal-window-when-gedit-is-opened) but that simply removed the warning. The icon didn't change.

[Picture of the default WSLg icon showing up with Eye of GNOME opened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMbWo.png)

In fact, all the apps that were installed have the default icons:
[A bunch of WSLg apps having the default icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h76n.png)

It should show up like it does in [this video](https://youtu.be/b1YBx1L8op4?t=414).

Comment: This issue is filed now on GitHub:
https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/614